# Link two contenteditable divs with content overflow / backflow

Tags: overflow, contenteditable

Good evening,

is it possible to link two contenteditable divs so that if text of div 1 automatically overflows in div 2 and "backflows" in div 1 if deleted again?

As in text editors like word, i want that a new page (div) is created, if the first overflows but also text from higher pages flow back into lower pages if text is deleted. Also with Images and other elements.

Is something like that possible with HTML / CSS / javascript?
I know that in firefox an on overflow event listener is working which doesnt work in other browsers...

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: Please create a snippet of your current relevant code. It makes answering much easier.

Comment: Actually i have not really yet started coding. I just wanted to know, if a solution with html/javascript is possible.